# java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX not initialized yet

Tags: android, android-camerax

Im following this [Google Codelab about CameraX](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/)

And when I get to the part of adding a Camera preview, I do it like this:

```
val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(1, 1))
            setTargetResolution(Size(640, 640))
            setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
        }.build()

        val preview = Preview(previewConfig)

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
            val parent = previewView.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.removeView(previewView)
            parent.addView(previewView, 0)

            previewView.surfaceTexture =     previewOutput.surfaceTexture
        updateTransform()
        }


        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview)
```

And then I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.<clinit>(Preview.java:55)
        at com.grow.vision.ImagePreviewActivity.startCamera(ImagePreviewActivity.kt:120)
        at com.grow.vision.ImagePreviewActivity.access$startCamera(ImagePreviewActivity.kt:28)
        at com.grow.vision.ImagePreviewActivity$onCreate$1.run(ImagePreviewActivity.kt:140)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX not initialized yet.
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.getCameraDeviceSurfaceManager(CameraX.java:485)
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.getSurfaceManager(CameraX.java:282)
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview$Defaults.<clinit>(Preview.java:416)
        at androidx.camera.core.Preview.<clinit>(Preview.java:55)
```

Seems like I need to initialise CameraX somehow but neither the codelab or the CameraX documentation references something like that.

Has someone had this issue before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I found the problem.
Did you add Camera2 to your dependencies? I left it out thinking it wasn't necessary, but it's in the guide. I added it and that error stopped.

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks exactly the same as mine, except mine has a `CameraX.unbindAll()` call at the top before I initialize `Preview` and call `CameraX.bindtoLifeCycle()`. I remember seeing something like the error you posted before I added `CameraX.unbindAll()`, so give that a try?

Comment: No, it didn't worked. Im try re-writing the code lab and see if that helps