# CameraX is not initialized properly. Either CameraX.initialize() needs to have been called or the CameraXConfig.Provider

Tags: android

I am using the new camerax (Dec 04, 2019) as per release notes (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-core-1.0.0-alpha07) and see an error that CameraX is not initialized. My test phone is a Nokia 5 and was previously working with older version of the CameraX dependency. 
I'd appreciate any help to guide me thru this error at getInstance() method.

Similar question [java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX not initialized yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227684/java-lang-illegalstateexception-camerax-not-initialized-yet)

cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

**crashes here**

```
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = (ProcessCameraProvider) cameraProviderFuture.get();
            bindPreview(cameraProvider);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
```

**Exception is as below:**

> Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
>       Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
>   D/CameraActivity: onCreate: 
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.camx, PID: 26631
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camx/com.example.camx.CameraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX is not initialized properly. Either CameraX.initialize() needs to have been called or the CameraXConfig.Provider interface must be implemented by your Application class.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX is not initialized properly. Either CameraX.initialize() needs to have been called or the CameraXConfig.Provider interface must be implemented by your Application class.
>           at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.getOrCreateInstance(CameraX.java:797)
>           at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ProcessCameraProvider.java:98)
>           at com.example.camx.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:92)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26631 SIG: 9
>   Process 26631 terminated.

**Gradle Dependency:**

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha07"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

Comment: Also, make sure you're using the same/compatible versions of those camera libraries.  I had 1 that was v1.0.0-alpha31 and another that was v1.1.0-beta1, which caused a crash at runtime.  Making them all v1.1.0-beta1 fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

Reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-camera2-1.0.0-alpha07

As mentioned in CameraX reference, dev should implement the `CameraXConfig.Provider` in Application class

> CameraX initialization has changed. Applications should implement CameraXConfig.Provider, and use the default Camera2Config provided by androidx.camera.camera2

```
import androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config
import androidx.camera.core.CameraXConfig

public class MyCameraXApplication : Application(),  CameraXConfig.Provider {
    override fun getCameraXConfig(): CameraXConfig {
            return Camera2Config.defaultConfig(this)
    }
}
```