# CameraX crashing randomly with IllegalStateException

Tags: android, camera, androidx, android-camerax

I'm using CameraX API in my app. I have bound a Preview UseCase and an ImageAnalysis UseCase to an Activity lifecycle like

```
preview.previewSurfaceProvider = frontFacingCameraPreviewSurface.previewSurfaceProvider
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(mainExecutor, myAnalyzer)
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis)
```

The app works most of the time but randomly crashes with following logs

> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.411 6581-6614/com.my.app D/Camera: Resetting Capture Session
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.411 6581-6614/com.my.app D/Camera: releasing session in state CLOSING
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.413 6581-6955/com.my.app D/Surface: setPackageUsesOwnResolution() (native) for "n0x8d8e9000" (SurfaceTexture-0-6581-22): false
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.477 6581-6594/com.my.app I/CameraManagerGlobal: postSingleUpdate device: camera id 1 status STATUS_PRESENT
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.478 6581-6594/com.my.app I/CameraManagerGlobal: postSingleUpdate device: camera id 1 status STATUS_PRESENT
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.480 6581-6614/com.my.app D/Camera: releasing session in state CLOSING
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.480 6581-6614/com.my.app D/Camera: CameraDevice.onClosed(): 1
>
> 2020-01-17 11:24:47.486 6581-6614/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-
>
> ```
> Process: com.my.app, PID: 6581
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>     at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:96)
>     at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:108)
>     at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.onClosed(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1298)
>     at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onClosed(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:105)
>     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$5.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:212)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
> ```

The exception occurs mostly during launching the activity or closing the activity. Any idea why it occurs?

Comment: Possible error at this piece of code on your snippet "this as LifecycleOwner".

Comment: Are you use some dependencies to CameraX? If no, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227684/java-lang-illegalstateexception-camerax-not-initialized-yet

Comment: Can you show the full code of the cameraX implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

i have somehow fix my issue by using updated version of camerax library and preview:

```
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha10"
    // If you want to use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha10"
    // If you want to use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
```

For more information proceed to this link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154070419